# BroadCast receiver not receiving incoming sms message

Tags: android, sms, android-manifest, android-broadcastreceiver

I am trying to read incoming message using receiver.I followed tutorial and added below code but broadcast receiver is not getting fired.Log placed inside onReceive never gets fired.

Manifest

```
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_SMS" />
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_SMS" />
<application
    android:name=".xyz"
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/icon_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <receiver android:name="xyz.receiver.SmsReceiver">
        <intent-filter android:priority="1">
            <action android:name="android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
```

BroadcastReceiver

```
public class SmsReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    private static SmsListener mListener;
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        Bundle data  = intent.getExtras();
        Log.e("TEST",data.toString());
        Object[] pdus = (Object[]) data.get("pdus");
        for(int i=0;i<pdus.length;i++){
            SmsMessage smsMessage = SmsMessage.createFromPdu((byte[]) pdus[i]);
            String sender = smsMessage.getDisplayOriginatingAddress();

            String messageBody = smsMessage.getMessageBody();

            mListener.messageReceived(messageBody);
        }
    }
    public static void bindListener(SmsListener listener) {
        mListener = listener;
    }
}
```

Activity

```
SmsReceiver.bindListener(new SmsListener() {
    @Override
    public void messageReceived(String messageText) {

        Toast.makeText(OTPActivity.this, "Message: " + messageText, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
});
```

Comment: is the package name proper? `<receiver android:name="xyz.receiver.SmsReceiver">` try changing it to `<receiver android:name=".SmsReceiver">`

Comment: @Darshan it's proper..I tried with tht also..

Comment: okay. Try adding these lines in your receiver in manifest and intent-filter respectively `<receiver android:permission="android.permission.BROADCAST_SMS" android:exported="true">
    <intent-filter android:priority="999"` As per this article http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19500381/broadcast-receiver-not-working-for-sms there are some bugs with few phones.

Comment: Since Android 6.0 (API level 23) or when Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M You should also check permissions at run time.

Answer (score 0):

I have used this code, hope this works for you too :)

```
private BroadcastReceiver mSMSReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        try {
            Log.e("sms receiver", "0000sdfghjkjhgfdsdfghjk");
            if (intent.getAction().equals("android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED")) {
                Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();
                if (bundle != null) {
                    Object[] pdus = (Object[]) bundle.get("pdus");
                    String sms;
                    for (Object pdu : pdus) {
                        SmsMessage tmp;
                        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
                            tmp = SmsMessage.createFromPdu((byte[]) pdu, bundle.getString("format"));
                        } else {
                            tmp = SmsMessage.createFromPdu((byte[]) pdu);
                        }
                        String senderMobile = tmp.getMessageBody();
                        sms = tmp.getMessageBody();
                        if (senderMobile.startsWith("کد فعالسازی شما در توپ 360:")) {
                            Log.e("sms receiver", "1111sdfghjkjhgfdsdfghjk");
                            final String mSMS = sms.replaceAll("[^0-9]", "");
                            //TODO Check SMS Center number with senderMobile if(senderMobile.equals(989100000)){...}
                            if (mSMS.length() == 5 || mSMS.length() == 6) {
                                Log.e("sms receiver", "2222sdfghjkjhgfdsdfghjk");
                                runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                                    @Override
                                    public void run() {
                                        //CODE IS mSMS
                                        code.setText(mSMS);
                                        Log.e("sms receiver", "3333sdfghjkjhgfdsdfghjk");
                                    }
                                });
                                abortBroadcast();
                                break;
                            }
                        }


                    }
                }
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("sms exception", e.getMessage());
        }
    }
};


@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();


    if (isGranted) {
        IntentFilter mIntentFilter = new IntentFilter();
        Log.e("sms receiver", "4444sdfghjkjhgfdsdfghjk");
        mIntentFilter.addAction("android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED");
        mIntentFilter.setPriority(Integer.MAX_VALUE);
        registerReceiver(mSMSReceiver, mIntentFilter);
    } else {

        Log.e("sms receiver", "5555sdfghjkjhgfdsdfghjk");
    }
}


@Override
public void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    if (isRegistered) {
        unregisterReceiver(mSMSReceiver);
        Log.e("sms receiver", "6666sdfghjkjhgfdsdfghjk");
    }
}



@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode,
                                       String permissions[], int[] grantResults) {
    switch (requestCode) {
        case 100: {
            // If request is cancelled, the result arrays are empty.

            if (grantResults.length > 0 && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

                isGranted = true;
                IntentFilter mIntentFilter = new IntentFilter();
                mIntentFilter.addAction("android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED");
                mIntentFilter.setPriority(Integer.MAX_VALUE);
                registerReceiver(mSMSReceiver, mIntentFilter);
                Log.e("sms receiver", "7777sdfghjkjhgfdsdfghjk");
                isRegistered = true;
                onResume();
            } else {
                isGranted = false;
                Snackbar snackbar = Snackbar.make(coordinatorLayout, "دریافت کننده خودکار پیامک غیرفعال است.", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG);
                snackbar.show();
            }
            return;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Starting from 4.4 few behaviours has been changed. May be that is causing issue on your end. Have a look on this android blog: https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2013/10/getting-your-sms-apps-ready-for-kitkat.html