# Broadcast Receiver for RECEIVE_SMS is not working when declared in manifest(statically)

Tags: android, sms, android-manifest, android-broadcastreceiver

I am trying to detect SMS received and read it via `texttospeech`.

when i declare the Broadcast Receiver in `manifest` it doesn't work. But it works when done dynamically in an activity.

I am aware that some Broadcast actions cant be caught in a receiver when declared in manifest and requires an activity(as mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10876015/3929188)), but have seen people using RECEIVE_SMS in manifest as in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19500636/3929188).

I don't know what I am doing wrong. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

**AndroidManifest.xml**

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        package="com.bulsy.smstalk1">
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_SMS" />
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_SMS" />
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SEND_SMS"/>
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS" />

        <application
            android:allowBackup="true"
            android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:supportsRtl="true"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
            <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
                <intent-filter>
                    <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                    <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
                </intent-filter>
            </activity>
            <receiver android:name="com.bulsy.smstalk1.SmsListener"
                   android:enabled="true" 
                   android:permission="android.permission.BROADCAST_SMS"
                   android:exported="true">   
                <intent-filter android:priority="2147483647">//this doesnt work
                    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                    <action android:name="android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED" />
                </intent-filter>
            </receiver>
        </application>   
    </manifest>
```

**SmsListener.java**

```
public class SmsListener extends BroadcastReceiver{

    private SharedPreferences preferences;
    TextToSpeech textToSpeech;
    String msg_from;
    public SmsListener()
    {

    }

    @Override
    public void onReceive(final Context context, Intent intent) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        if(intent.getAction().equals("android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED")){

            Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();           //---get the SMS message passed in---
            SmsMessage[] msgs = null;

            if (bundle != null){
                //---retrieve the SMS message received---
                try{
                    Object[] pdus = (Object[]) bundle.get("pdus");
                    msgs = new SmsMessage[pdus.length];
                    for(int i=0; i<msgs.length; i++){
                        msgs[i] = SmsMessage.createFromPdu((byte[])pdus[i]);
                        msg_from = msgs[i].getOriginatingAddress();
                        final String msgBody = msgs[i].getMessageBody();
                        textToSpeech = new TextToSpeech(context, new TextToSpeech.OnInitListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onInit(int status) {
                                if(status != TextToSpeech.ERROR) {
                                    textToSpeech.setLanguage(Locale.UK);
                                    String fromName = getContactName(context,msg_from);
                                    fromName = fromName==null? msg_from:fromName;
                                    textToSpeech.speak("You have a text message from " + fromName + ". Content: " + msgBody , TextToSpeech.QUEUE_FLUSH, null);
                                }
                            }
                        }
                        );


                    }
                }catch(Exception e){
//                            Log.d("Exception caught",e.getMessage());
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

**MainActivity.java**

```
    public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        SmsListener smsListener = new SmsListener();//Dynamically setting the receiver. this works.
        IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter();
        filter.addAction("android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED");
        this.registerReceiver(smsListener,filter);
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you sure the `<receiver>`'s `name` is pointing to the right place? When you test your manifest Receiver, are you launching your `MainActivity` at least once after installation? Btw, the `<category>` is not necessary in the `<intent-filter>`, and the `enabled` and `exported` attributes aren't needed on the `<receiver>`.

Comment: The receiver should be pointing to the rightplace. com.bulsy.smstalk1.SmsListener. `com.bulsy.smstalk1` is my package name and `SmsListener` is my class name. Even tried with `.SmsListener` and `SmsListener`. None worked. I removed `enabled exported category` attributes. Still didn't work.

Comment: Yeah, the `<category>`, `exported`, and `enabled` won't prevent it from working. I was just saying you don't need them. Those `name` attributes are fine, if your Receiver is in the same folder/package as `MainActivity`. Also, what about my other question? Are you running your `Activity` once after installation when you test the manifest Receiver?

Comment: Yes. It will be. It is the launcher activity. So in android studio if I launch the app in my phone installation takes place first and then the app is run with the launcher activity triggered.

Comment: How are you determining that the Receiver isn't working? I just noticed you don't have any log prints or `Toast`s or anything there. The TTS is probably not going to work in a manifest-registered instance, since the Receiver will die before the engine's ready. You'll need to move that functionality to a `Service`, in that case, but you should first see if that's the problem, if it's just the TTS not working.

Comment: It worked!! You got it spot on! Kindly post it as an answer if it doesn't matter, so i can accept it.

Comment: does this work on oreo? because i have the same problem broadcast is not working for oreo. rest of the versions are working fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The root of the problem here is the lifetime of a manifest-registered Receiver instance. An instance of such a Receiver will only be alive until the `onReceive()` method completes. The `TextToSpeech` object will not be ready before the Receiver dies, and without any other indication of the Receiver working, it appears as though the Receiver has just failed.

The solution is to move the `TextToSpeech` functionality to a `Service` you can run from the Receiver, and pass the necessary info as extras on the `Intent` used to start it.

Comment: is an `IntentService` sufficient to execute whatever needs to be done when the SMS is received ?

Comment: @SomeoneSomewhere Probably not for a `TextToSpeech` instance, for the same reason as the Receiver, unless you do something to block in `onHandleIntent()`. I've not tested anything, though.